# Uber Surge Confirmation page

Tags: uber-api

The Href that is provided by uber as a surge confirmation page ,What happens when i click on the I accept the pricing,does it open a new page as where we need to fill the surge multiplier(numeric),or it directly confirms my ride.

Is it a necessary compulsion that after clicking on the I accept the high price,i need to submit the surge multiplier in numeric`s,or it can skipped or uber does that automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whenever there is surge in Uber and request is made to API I get response code 409 and text "Surge Applicable". How do I handle this? I don't even get surge confirmation url from the API. Normally surge is 1.7 to 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the surge is high (i believe `>= 2.0`) Uber uses this scheme of confirmation.

Otherwise, this numeric page is not shown.

There is no possibility to affect this using Uber API, in my current understanding.